# Background image appears on form input

Tags: html, css

I am using Python flask and flask-wtf to create form input fields. Whenever I have 3 or more input fields the first field automatically gets a background image in Chrome as seen in the image below

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? I have tried setting background-image to none and it then changes the image to this in stead

[image]

The order or type of my form fields does not seem to matter, its always the first field, i have tried adding another hidden field first, but it stille shows the image on the first visible field

The code for my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
    <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="IjY3NmQ2OTk5MjIxZWRjODdlODIwNjM3N2U4NjhiMDU2NDBkMjUxMmEi.YkqQbg.-v0ZkwCGxLOoHJbnH8I9Xx0h4ag">
    <fieldset class="form-field">
        <label for="regNo">CVR Nummer</label>
        <input id="regNo" name="regNo" required size="20" type="text" value="">
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset class="form-field">
        <label for="companyName">Firmanavn</label>
        <input id="companyName" name="companyName" required size="20" type="text" value="">
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset class="form-field">
        <label for="name">Navn</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" required size="20" type="text" value="">
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset class="form-field">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" required size="20" type="text" value="">
    </fieldset>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Opret konto">

</form>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="text"] {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

The affected input field gets this added:

```
<input id="regNo" name="regNo" required="" size="20" type="text" value="" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: pointer;">
```

Comment: can you please share a code to understand more

Comment: How is the image generated in the first place?

Comment: Looks like Chrome UA might be adding these images

Comment: Just tested in FF & brave and it's not the UA

Comment: Does not pop up in Edge

Comment: _"The affected input field gets this added:"_ - probably some browser extension interfering then ...?

Comment: That looks like the LastPass browser extension that is doing that.  If you are using LastPass and are logged in on your Chrome browser, try logging out and see if that corrects the problem.  If it does, as far as I know, there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I do indeed use lastpass, and it seems that this is the issue

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got some browser extension which is doing this.

The only suggestion would seem to be the rather unpleasant forcing of the background image to nothing:

```css
#regNo {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

```html
<input id="regNo" name="regNo" required="" size="20" type="text" value="" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: pointer;">
```

Comment: I think you are right, incognito mode does not display the image, and there is a lastpass add-on on my chrome, must be it